# How to change Date format (dd-mmm-yyyy) in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

**Script**

```html
<script>
  $(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

**Textbox**

```html
<input class="datepicker" id="_Date" name="Date" type="text" value="01-Jan-2017">
```

[image]

When I select date form textbox then the format looks like **10/11/2017** but I need the format like **11-Oct-2017**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [format](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format) option of bootstrap datepicker

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'd-M-yyyy'
    });
});
```

> d: Numeric date
>
> M: Abbreviated month names
>
> yyyy: 4-digit years

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o31w8k6v/)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:
`format: "DD MMM YYYY"`