# how to change the format of the bootsrap datepicker to dd-monthname-yyyy

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, format

I want to get the date format in the form of `30-sep-2019` instead of `30-09-2019`

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.form-control.fromdate').datepicker({ format: "mm-dd-yyyy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group fromdate" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
     <input type="text" class="form-control fromdate" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" id="FromDate" runat="server" data-date-container="#formDiv" />
     <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Date format (dd-mmm-yyyy) in bootstrap datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008678/how-to-change-date-format-dd-mmm-yyyy-in-bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate), try using:

```js
format: 'dd-M-yyyy'
```

```js
$('#table').datepicker({
  format: 'dd-M-yyyy'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='input-group date datepicker' id='table'>
  <input type='text' name="tgl" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to `$('.form-control.fromdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-MMM-yy' }).val();`